# How to set TTL on Google Cloud Platform's Memory Store Redis Cache Server

Tags: caching, google-cloud-platform, redis, spring-data-redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I have a SpringBoot application that uses the `@Cacheable` annotation over a method with Redis Caching.
I have `@EnableCaching` in my main SpringBootApplication class, and in my application.yml file for the project I have these properties:

```
spring.cache.cache-names: getMyMethodCache
spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
    redis:
      time-to-live: 300000 # 5 minutes
```

When I do this locally, I can connect to redis-cli and see that the method is successfully caching with the Time-To-Live that was specified by running
`127.0.0.1:6379> TTL "myKeyName"`.

I am trying to connect my App Engine Instance on Google Cloud Platform to a Memory Store Redis Instance. The instance is created with all of the default values and gave me an IP address and port, which I placed into my .properties file for my service.

As a side note, setting spring.cache.redis.time-to-live changes the default TTL throughout the application for all redis cache keys. This works locally.

After making a few calls to my web service via Postman, I waited a few minutes (Memory Store has a delay) and saw that my keys were showing up in the Memory Store "Keys in Database" location. I then wait another 5 minutes and see that they are never expiring.

I then exported the Redis Memory Store database and ran it through the RDB tools command via `rdb --c protocol export.rdb` and got some funky looking output containing this:

```
$8
EXPIREAT
$83
getMyMethodKey::TheResponseThatWasCached
$10
1573335619
*3
```

I found out that the EXPIREAT is referring to the "1573335619" which is a Unix timestamp for Nov 9, one month from now.
Long story short, I'm trying to get my Redis Memory Store to respond to my custom default time to live, but it doesn't seem to be registering my properties in my yaml file.

Any help as to how to set the EXPIRE property of a memory store cache key would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Comment: Hey @hsander, could you please post the full configuration of your app.yaml file for App Engine so I can help you further? I can see that your app works good locally but you are facing problems in production so I guess the issue lies in app.yaml file.